# Shape of a unit Ball and metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, convex-geometry

Playing around with metrics defined in $\Bbb{R}^2$, such as $d_p$, where $p\ge1$, or even such as $σ=\sqrt{d_p}, τ=\frac{d_p}{1+d_p},π=\min \{1,d_p\}$, I realised that all produce sets in $\Bbb{R}^2$ ("unit balls") that are convex sets: [image].

So I wonder if there is a metric in $\Bbb{R}^2$, such as its respective unit ball is **not convex, or not simply connected.**
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$Suppose a metric $d$ is induced by a norm. The $d$-unit ball is convex by homogeneity and the triangle inequality: If the unit ball is not convex, then there exist points $\Vec{x}$ and $\Vec{y}$ a real $t$ with $0 < t < 1$ such that $|\Vec{x}| < 1$ and $|\Vec{y}| < 1$ but $|(1 - t)\Vec{x} + t\Vec{y}| \geq 1$, so either homogeneity or the triangle inequality fails.

---

For a "[roundhouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railway_roundhouse)-type" metric
$$
d(\Vec{x}, \Vec{y}) = \begin{cases}
  |\Vec{x} - \Vec{y}| & \text{if $\Vec{x}$, $\Vec{y}$ lie on a line through the origin,} \\
  |\Vec{x}| + |\Vec{y}| & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$
a ball can fail to be convex. For example, the unit ball about $\Vec{x}_{0} := (\frac{3}{4}, 0)$ is the union of the ray from $\Vec{x}_{0} + (1, 0) = (\frac{7}{4}, 0)$ to the origin and the open Euclidean disk of radius $\frac{1}{4}$ about the origin.

(The distance function gives the Euclidean distance along lines through the origin. For points on different lines, the distance is the Euclidean length of the path from $\Vec{x}$ to $\Vec{0}$ to $\Vec{y}$ along rays.)

To find a metric for which some unit ball about the origin is not simply-connected, think of the graph of a smooth function with a tall spike at a point close to the origin, such as
$$
f(x, y) = 10e^{-10,000[(x - 0.1)^{2} + y^{2}]},
$$
and define $d(\Vec{x}, \Vec{y})$ to be the infimum of the Euclidean arc lengths of smooth paths *on the graph* joining the point over $\Vec{x}$ to the point over $\Vec{y}$. The spike in the graph makes traveling close to the center of the spike "costly" in terms of distance, so the unit ball oozes around the spike, giving an annulus.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. I think the unit ball should consist of the union of the ray from (7/4,0) to (0,0) and the open eukleidian ball centered in (0,0) with radius 1/4

Comment: Yes, thank you, brain slip on my part.